# how to join two table only when foreign key value is not null

Tags: laravel

I want to join right (`employees`) table only when left (`purchases`) table's `employee_id` is `NOT NULL` but the query returning empty result set if the `employee_id` is `NULL`.

```
$data = DB::table('purchases')
            ->join('demands', 'purchases.demand_id', 'demands.id')
            ->join('fiscal_years', 'purchases.fiscal_year_id', 'fiscal_years.id')
            ->join('employees', function ($join){
                $join->on('purchases.employee_id', 'employees.id')
                    ->where('purchases.employee_id', '!=', null);
            })
            ->select('purchases.*', 'demands.code', 'fiscal_years.year', 'employees.name')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use leftJoin. It will join employees if they are.

```
$data = DB::table('purchases')
            ->join('demands', 'purchases.demand_id', 'demands.id')
            ->join('fiscal_years', 'purchases.fiscal_year_id', 'fiscal_years.id')
            ->leftJoin('employees', function ($join){
                $join->on('purchases.employee_id', 'employees.id')
                    ->where('purchases.employee_id', '!=', null);
            })
            ->select('purchases.*', 'demands.code', 'fiscal_years.year', 'employees.name')
            ->get();
```